# These relative modules were not found vue cli

Tags: node.js, webpack, vuejs2, stylus, yarnpkg

My 'App.vue' style is:

```
<style lang="stylus">
    @import "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
    @import "~bootstrap-4-grid"
    @import "assets/styl/app.styl"
</style>
```

After running

```
yarn dev
```

on default vue-cli webpack config, I am getiing:

```
These relative modules were not found:

* ../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-04c2046b","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/stylus-loader?{"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0&bustCache!./src/App.vue
* ../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.7.0 in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-04c2046b","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/stylus-loader?{"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0&bustCache!./src/App.vue
* ../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.7.0 in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-04c2046b","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/stylus-loader?{"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0&bustCache!./src/App.vue
* ../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.7.0 in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-04c2046b","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/stylus-loader?{"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0&bustCache!./src/App.vue
* ../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0 in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-04c2046b","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/stylus-loader?{"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0&bustCache!./src/App.vue
* ../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.7.0 in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-04c2046b","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/stylus-loader?{"sourceMap":false}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0&bustCache!./s
```

Did someone faced the same issue?

Answer (score 3):

Replace this :

```
@import "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
```

by this :

```
@import "~font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css"
```